# Output MIDI number back to user

Tags: c++, midi

I'm at the last hurdle of a long project. The final step is to convert a string of noteNames to MIDI numbers, and output these numbers back to the user. I've written a suitable code to convert the characters (C-B) to MIDI numbers, but I now need to output these numbers back to the user. I'm not sure where to store them to be able to recall them... Any pointers would be great! I am an absolute amateur to coding so please forgive any ignorance. Also, for some reason when I copy and paste the code from the app it ruins the layout, so apologies in advance.

```
‪#‎include‬ <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <vector> 

using namespace std;
 int notenumber;
 struct noteStorage {
  string noteName;
  string bassnoteName;
  int midiNumber;
  int noteLength;
  int bassnoteLength;
}
;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//VALIDATION FOR NOTE NAME
bool ValidateNote(string note) {
  // Step 1: If note name length is less than 2 OR more than 3, return false
  if (note.length() <2 || note.length() >3) {
    cout<<"Note length must be 2 or 3 characters\n";
return false;
  }
  //Step 2: If true, the note must be/(or be) between A and G
  else if(tolower(note[0])<'a' || tolower(note[0]) >'g') {
    cout<<"Note must be A-G\n";
return false;
  }
  //Step 3: If true, the last character must be a digit
  else if(isdigit(note[note.length()-1])==false) {
    cout<<"Last character must be a digit\n";
return false;
  }
  //Step 4: If note length is 3 note[1] (character 2) must be '#'.
  else if(note.length()==3 && note[1] !='#') {
    "Invalid sharp note\n";
return false;
  }
  return true;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//VALIDATION FOR NOTE LENGTH
bool ValidateNoteLength (int length)//Step 1 - If notelength is not a digit, return FALSE
 {
  if (length==false) {
    cout<<"Note length must be a digit/number, please re-enter";
    return false;
  }
  //Step 2 - If notelength is less than or equal to 0 or more than 16, return FALSE
  if (length <=0 || length > 16) {
    cout<<"Note length value cannot be less than 1 or more than 16, please re-enter";
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int CalculateNoteNumber(string tempName) {
  int Octave;
  int notenumber;
  tempName[0]=toupper(tempName[0]);
  Octave=((tempName[tempName.length()-1]) -48) * 12;
  if (tempName.length()==2) {
    if(tempName[0]=='C') {
      return notenumber=0;
    }
    else if(tempName[0]=='D') {
      return notenumber=2;
    }
    else if(tempName[0]=='E') {
      return notenumber=4;
    }
    else if(tempName[0]=='F') {
      return notenumber=5;
    }
    else if(tempName[0]=='G') {
      return notenumber=7;
    }
    else if(tempName[0]=='A') {
      return notenumber=9;
    }
    else {
      return notenumber=11;
    }
  }
  else if (tempName.length()==3) {
    if(tempName[0]=='C') {
      return notenumber=1;
    }
    else if(tempName[0]=='D') {
      return notenumber=3;
    }
    else if(tempName[0]=='F') {
      return notenumber=6;
    }
    else if(tempName[0]=='G') {
      return notenumber=8;
    }
    else {
      return notenumber=10;
    }
  }
}
int main() {
  noteStorage noteData[8];
  //string note;
  for (int i=0;
  i < 8;
  i++) {
    cout<<"Please enter melody note: " << i <<": ";
    while (1) {
      string tempName;
      cin>>tempName;
      int noteNumber=CalculateNoteNumber(tempName);
      if (ValidateNote(tempName)==true) {
        noteData[i].noteName=tempName;
        break;
      }
      else {
        cout <<"Please enter correctly: ";
      }
    }
    //end first while
    cout<<"Please enter note length: ";
    while (1) {
      int tempLength;
      cin>>tempLength;
      if (ValidateNoteLength(tempLength)==true) {
        noteData[i].noteLength=tempLength;
        break;
      }
      else {
        cout <<"Please enter correctly: ";
      }
    }
    //end while 2
    cout<<"Thank you\n";
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  }
  // Bass Melody Input
  {
    noteStorage noteData[8];
    //string note;
    for (int i=0;
    i < 8;
    i++) {
      cout<<"Please enter bass melody note: " << i <<": ";
      while (1) {
        string basstempName;
        cin>>basstempName;
        int noteNumber=CalculateNoteNumber(basstempName);
        if (ValidateNote(basstempName)==true) {
          noteData[i].bassnoteName=basstempName;
          break;
        }
        else {
          cout <<"Please enter correctly: ";
        }
      }
      //end first while
      cout<<"Please enter note length: ";
      while (1) {
        int basstempLength;
        cin>>basstempLength;
        if (ValidateNoteLength(basstempLength)==true) {
          noteData[i].bassnoteLength=basstempLength;
          break;
        }
        else {
          cout <<"Please enter correctly: ";
        }
      }
      //end while 2
      cout<<"Thank you\n";

    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  }
  //end for
  cout<<"Your melody notes and note lengths are: "<<endl;
  for (int i=0;
  i < 8;
  i++) {
    cout<<noteData[i].noteName<<"Length: ";
    cout<<noteData[i].noteLength<<endl;
  }
  cout<<"Your bass notes and note lengths are: "<<endl;
  for (int i=0;
  i < 8;
  i++) {
    cout<<noteData[i].bassnoteName<<"Length: ";
    cout<<noteData[i].bassnoteLength<<endl;
  }
  /*system("pause");
return 0;
*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just about there!  `int noteNumber=CalculateNoteNumber(tempName);` is already storing the info you need in `noteNumber`.  `cout` supports different types including `int`, so you can do, for example: `cout << endl << "Current note MIDI number: " << noteNumber` to write a new line out to stdout with the note number.

Does that address what you're looking for?

Comment: That's kind of it, except I want to output midi number equivelants of all of the notes that have been stored, at the end of the project. In the same place as where the note lengths and note names are outputted